# Putting large number of documents: Google App Engine and Search API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api

It is question about limit on putting large number of documents in Search API. I intend to put 2057 documents(paragraphs from text file). When I parse each paragraph from text file, create document for each paragraph and put it into index, app seems to be running forever and not responding at all. What can be reason for such behavior?

With regards

Comment: well, what do the logs say?

Comment: Does it timeout? Is anything being added to your Search indexes at all? As the previous commenter asked - is anything showing up in the logs? Can you provide some code to show what exactly you are doing?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood, thanks for replies. I understood that it takes a long time when importing large number of documents to index.

Comment: I will delete question, nevertheless thanks to you

Comment: no, not really. It's been a while since I did it but I seem to recall importing 1/4 million documents in a not unreasonable amount of time. Break the import into chunks are report on each chunk as it's processed

Comment: Really? I also heard something like that:                             "You can pass up to 200 documents at a time when adding or deleting them from an index. This is much more efficient that handling them one at a time." I will try do what you are advising.

Comment: 2057 paragraphs should take a few seconds. If you do a lot of work with them, maybe a minute.

Comment: So it takes about 10 minutes. I read each line and adding to document. Is this efficient way? How can I improve it?

Comment: I improved time of putting, here is the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched the documentation and found the following method:

```
put(java.lang.Iterable<Document> documents)
```

My way of importing like this:

```
1. I collect all documents to be put into index in collector(ArrayList, List) until 200 documents(it's limit by GAE)
2. Put this collector into this method
```

In my case, it decreased the time of putting by **100** times